# How do I mock $location.host() in angularjs tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, angularjs, mocking

I have created an `Env` service which wraps up environment information, and I'm currently using `$location.host()` to determine what environment I'm in. How do I mock that in my tests?

I've read https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/F0jFWC4G9hI, but it doesn't seem to work, for example:

```
describe("Env (environment) service", function() {

  var Env;

  beforeEach(module('App'));

  beforeEach(inject(
    ['Env', function(e) {
      Env = e;
    }]
  ));

  describe("for staging", function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function($location, $rootScope) {
      $location.host("http://staging-site.com");
      $rootScope.$apply();
    }));

    it("returns envrionment as staging", function() {
      expect(Env.environment).toEqual("staging");
    });

    it("returns .isStaging() as true", function() {
      expect(Env.isStaging()).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

I've also tried the `$browser` variant, but that doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: I've also tried `$browser.url()` as per http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/angular-location-testing, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I need to inject $location into my test since the service requires it.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/493

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to use spies IMHO: http://tobyho.com/2011/12/15/jasmine-spy-cheatsheet/

```
// inject $location
spyOn($location, "host").andReturn("super.domain.com");
var host = $location.host();
alert(host) // is "super.domain.com"
expect($location.host).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Syntax for jasmine 2.0 and greater has changed as follows

```
// inject $location
spyOn($location, "host").and.returnValue("super.domain.com");
var host = $location.host();
alert(host) // is "super.domain.com"
expect($location.host).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Syntax for jasmine 2.0 and greater has changed, you should use .and.returnValue()

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem and have used $injector service. (I don't know if it is the simplest solution, but it worked for me :) )

Since $location cannot be relied in during tests I have prepared my own mock.
First, you need to create a factory method. (Or service or provider if you prefer - see https://gist.github.com/Mithrandir0x/3639232 for comparison):

```
function locationFactory(_host) {
  return function () {
    return {
      /* If you need more then $location.host(), add more methods */
      host: function () {
        return _host;
      }
    };
  };
}
```

Then **before you create your 'Env'**, feed injector with this $location mock:

```
module(function ($provide) {
  $provide.factory('$location', locationFactory('http://staging-site.com'));
});
```

Now every time your access $location in your code your mock is injected, so it returns whatever you need it to.
More on $provide method is in [angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide)

Hope this helps you in the future.

Update: I see one place when you might have gone wrong (or which at least would be wrong in my solution). It seems like you are initiating you 'Env' module (which I guess calculates the data immediately) and only after this you change $location - which might be already too late.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good example in the doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

You want to make sure to use `$provide` before you instantiate the service. I like to use `$injector` in the testcase, to first decide the location then instantiate the service.

```
  var mockLocation;

  beforeEach(function() {
    // control the $location.host() function
    // which we fake in the testcases.
    mockLocation = {
      host: jasmine.createSpy()
    };
    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('$location', mockLocation);
    });
  });
```

then

```
  describe('staging server:', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      // mockLocation.host.andReturn('http://staging-site.com'); // jasmine 1.x
      mockLocation.host.and.returnValue('http://staging-site.com');
    });

    it('returns envrionment as staging', inject(function($injector) {
      Env = $injector.get('Env');
      expect(Env.environment).toEqual('staging');
    }));
  });
```

and

```
  describe('production server:', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      // mockLocation.host.andReturn('prod.example.com'); // jasmine 1.x
      mockLocation.host.and.returnValue('prod.example.com');
    });

    it('returns envrionment as production', inject(function($injector) {
      Env = $injector.get('Env');
      expect(Env.environment).toEqual('production');
    }));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to mock $location, with Sinon.js

```
    locationMock = {
        path: sinon.spy()
    };
```

And an example assertion:

```
locationMock.path.should.be.calledWith('/home');
```